# EL - access an applicationScoped hashMap's entries with request object

Tags: java, jsp, el

I have a hashmap stored in application Scope, I want to pass the key from input (String) and retrieve the corresponding (value) ArrayList, then iterate over the arrayList and perform some operations -

```
           HashMap<String,List> envList
```

I have a form input variable "acno" defined in the jsp

Intuitively, something like - ${applicationScope[envList[param.acno]]} should be supported

This gives an error though and I have tried a few work-arounds , for instance, setting the input to a page scoped variable (account)  -

```
        input ac no. : ${param.acno}
        <c:set var="account" value=" ${param.acno}"/>
        param set : ${account}

         envs -  ${applicationScope[envList[account]]}
         <c:forEach var ="row" items ="${applicationScope.envList[account]}">
          ${row}
         </c:forEach>
```

It doesn't seem to be working either, 
Note - ${applicationScope[envList["AMEX"]]}  -> returns the hashmap values (where AMEX is an account) but my problem arises when I use a variable here

Has anyone faced such an issue before? I'm more of a novice with JSP, would greatly appreciate any sort of assistance ..

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is attempting to use the list object as the key to the applicationScope variable instead of the parameter value.  You need to get the map out of the applicationScope before you can get the account from the map.

```
${applicationScope['envList'][param.acno]}
```